# Print a text at a specific location on the page

Tags: python

I have a web-application (developed using Web2py Python framework). In this web-app, I would like to print certificates for some courses.

The principle:
The course teacher has a "default" certificates, with placeholders for the name, and the certification name. ("Congratulations ***_*** you successfully passed the **__** course")
He puts the certificate in his printer, and my app prints the name, and the certification on a specific location, to fill the placeholders.

I looked at ReportLab, and Pod. They seems powerful to build complex reports, but I wonder if it exists a simpler solution just to print a text at a specific place on the page...

Comment: If the page is rendered as a template, use the name as a `variable`?!

Comment: You need to approach this by creating a template, then render that template as a PDF and then send the resulting PDF to the client (browser) for printing.

You cannot directly access the printer from a web browser. If you can provide details of the framework you are using; you'll get more specific answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the task is just positional printing to a newly created PDF then I'd go with [PyFPDF](http://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/).

Slightly extending their [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/wiki/Tutorial) (and skipping error handling etc. for simplicity):

```
from fpdf import FPDF
import sys

x1, x2, y = [int(arg) for arg in sys.argv[1:4]]

pdf=FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
pdf.set_xy(x1, y)
pdf.cell(0, 10, 'name')
pdf.set_xy(x2, y)
pdf.cell(0, 10, 'course')

pdf.output('tuto_%d_%d_%d.pdf' % (x1, x2, y),'F')
```

It accepts three arguments, x1 and x2 horizontal coordinates in millimeters for name and cert, and y as their common vertical position as in your example.

**Edit:** If you're using web2py that already [includes fpdf](http://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/wiki/Web2Py). Using [templates](http://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/wiki/Templates) may be an alternative (and possibly better) way.

Rendering HTML as PDF is also a possibility but proper positioning might be harder that way.